# TOAD - Import data from Excel without SQL*Loader

Tags: sql, oracle, toad

Is there a query or script that allows me to import data, or view data, in Toad for Oracle? I know I can do it by using the SQL*Loader functionality, but would like a script that can be quasi-carried over into other SQL software. Thanks!

I understand how to use the Wizard. I was looking for the actual code that is used. I've found that, but what I'm learning is there is no generic code that works for Oracle and, for example, SQL Server. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

i. You could write anything in any language that will parse the excel file and write insert statements to write to your table. Oracle has written one in C, called sqlloader, as you know and don't want to use.

ii. If your file is in CSV format (as opposed to XLS), then you could create an external table. But again you will be written Oracle specific DDL.

So it seems you could do a lot of hard work and have something generic (and probably slow), or you could just use the native tool for the database(s) you want to use.